# When navigating jetpack compose there is a recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

```
composable(Screens.Recommendation.route) {
    BackHandler(true) {}
    RecomendationScreen(
        onNavigateToStatistics = { navController.navigate(Screens.Statistics.route) }
    )
}
```

I pass a function for navigation, in its execution recomendation happens **RecomendationScreen** When you call this method does not change state, which would cause recomendation, the question is whether it should be, it comes out of the box, or still have to keep looking for a problem

```
fun RecomendationScreen(onNavigateToStatistics: () -> Unit) {
   RecomendationContent(onNavigateToStatistics) }
```

I tried to fix it by looking through the documentation to find an answer to my question but I couldn't find it, on top of that I searched for the source of recomposition but I couldn't find it either

Comment: Is "recomendation" supposed to be "recomposition"?   When exactly is the unexpection recomposition happening?

Comment: @RyanM  "recommendation" is "recomposable", but when you move to another screen it should not cause recomposition, the recomposition occurs after navigate() is called